# Scalar line integral over an explicit function

Tags: analysis, line-integrals

$$\int_D (x-y)\mathrm{d}x+y\mathrm{d}y$$ where $D: y=\sin x, x \in [0,\pi]$

[image: >the graph<]

I have no idea how to solve this, I barely did some line integrals of 1st kind if that's the correct english translation but for this one, I am not sure if i just do it the same way with the figure then parametrics then to calculate, and it'd help if I could get this as an example.

Comment: Can you evaluate each term's separate contribution, using $y=\sin x$ in the first one?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since y= sin(x), dy= cos(x)dx.

(x- y)dx+ ydy= (x- sin(x))dx- sin(x)cos(x)dx= (x- sin(x)- sin(x)cos(x))dx

So the integral is $\int_0^\pi (x- sin(x)- sin(x)cos(x))dx$.
That's easy to integrate.

Comment: Thanks, I did this integral as well and I got the same answer as the one I did, I posted my version of how I solved the problem a bit below in the comments, much appreciated the reply!